# How to demo an iPhone app on a projector

Tags: iphone

What is the best way to demo an iPhone app on a projector?
Preferably without jailbreaking and without using a separate camera to record the iPhone screen which might limit movement?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 4):

For DEMO purposes only you can do a custom build of your app using the private API for video mirroring

http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3

Comment: Thanks @starkhalo, I actually saw that link. Looks very promising, but that won't work if we're on the app though right? (meaning, we can't capture if the app takes me to youtube or internet or sms and won't even capture the iPhone main screen)?

Comment: No, unfortunately it only works under your app... you could always mock those though

Answer (score 3):

With the release of iOS 5, you can use the [Apple Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/B) or [VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE) to display the contents of your iPad 2 or iPhone 4S screen to a projector or other external display.

Answer (score 1):

Using the simulator would be easier.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't quite work if the app needs to use camera, multitouch, accelerometer right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [document camera](http://www2.smarttech.com/st/en-US/Products/SMART+Document+Camera/) if you need to demonstrate features which are not available in the Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no solved way to do this, which is why you see different places trying different things. Even at the Apple iPhone tech talks, the speakers use a pretty crappy projection solution.

It might be a better idea to prerecord a demo (Revision3 seems to have a pretty good setup) and then play a video instead of a live demonstration.

Hopefully Apple releases whatever they do during the Keynotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty little video demonstrating how it can be done [here](http://aralbalkan.com/2397).
However just remember that if you "accidentally" submit an app to the AppStore with this enabled you are probably going to get it rejected right away.

Claus

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
In my case I want to demo my app over gotomeeting session in one of our meeting rooms.
The meeting room is equipped with a PC and I also like to demo from a device.

After some longer research, I found that streaming the screen over WIFI is most acceptable for me.
Here is a Gist of my solution:
https://gist.github.com/1608099

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

We generally use Reflector app for demo purposes, it works really good. Only thing is you will have to buy the license to use.

http://www.reflectorapp.com

Comment: I was hoping to use Reflector and purchased a license. However, the combination of the mirror screen share, wifi, and other factors proved to unreliable.